# Enable right-click save images in a DIV background

Tags: image, background, right-click

I have had a small site built for me which has an issue. The slideshow images in it can not be downloaded by right-clicking on them. I believe it's because they are contained in the DIV background.

I'm not a developer, I'm just trying to troubleshoot this myself and learn. This is an example of the code:

```
<div class=​"swiper-slide c-swiper__slide" data-module=​"ResponsiveBackgroundImage" data-swiper-slide-index=​"6" style=​"width:​ 1431px;​ transform:​ translate3d(-10017px, 0px, 0px)​;​ opacity:​ 0;​ transition-duration:​ 0ms;​ background-image:​ url(thisistheimageIneedtoclick.jpg)​;​">​
```

If anyone knows if there is some CSS or some other method I can try to enable right-clicking I would be grateful.

Comment: As you said, the problem is that the image is set in CSS. Only way I can think of right now is either add the usual img tag or do some Javascript code

Comment: The plot thickens. It looks like there is a DIV sitting on top of this one, called c-loader which is getting in the way. If I set that to none, then I can right click images under it. So my question is, how can I leave that DIV there without it getting in the way? Is it possible to right-click 'through' another DIV that is sitting on top?